# Calcular média conforme total de uma "célula" em php

Tags: php

Estou precisando fazer um cálculo conforme resultado que obtenho da consulta onde ele efetuara apenas uma divisão do valor total de uma pessoa pela média que foi obtida de todos. 
Veja a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei se vai ajudar, mas parte do código é assim:

```
$idservico = 0;
$idservicoAnterior = -1;
$totalAtendimentos = 0;
$quantidadePessoas = 0;
$media = 0;

if(empty($mes) || empty($ano))
{
    echo "<script> alert('Favor preencha todos os campos.')</script>";
}else{

    if (isset($hostp))
    {
        $resulta = pg_fetch_array($consulta);
    } else {
        $resulta = $consulta->fetch_array();
    }
while ($resulta) {

    $idservico = $resulta['id_serv'];

    $media = @round($totalAtendimentos / $quantidadePessoas);

    if($idservico != $idservicoAnterior)
    {   
        if($idservicoAnterior != -1)
        {

            echo "<tr>
                    <td style='width: 200px; background-color: #D3D3D3;'></td>
                    <td style='background-color: #D3D3D3;'>Média</td>
                    <td style='background-color: #D3D3D3;'>$media</td>
                    <td style='background-color: #D3D3D3;'></td>
                  </tr>
                </table> <br/>";
        }

        $totalAtendimentos = 0;
        $quantidadePessoas = 0;

        echo "<table border=1>
              <tr style='background-color: #D3D3D3;'>
                <td>Setor</td>
                <td>{$resulta['nm_serv']}</td>
                <td>Total Atendimentos</td>
                <td>Percentual x Média</td>
              </tr>";
    }

    $totalAtendimentos += $resulta['total'];
    $quantidadePessoas += 1;
    $idservicoAnterior = $idservico;

    echo "<tr>
            <td>{$resulta['desc_serv']}</td>
            <td>{$resulta['nm_usu']}</td>
            <td>{$resulta['total']}</td>
            <td>O VALOR DO CÁLCULO VEM AQUI</td>

          </tr>";
```

Sei que o estilo de código não é o certo, mas é que estou aprendendo ainda. Caso precisem de mais alguma informação estou disponível a ajudar para ser ajudado.

Comment: Sim, eu já tentei fazer alguma coisa aqui, mas nada que desse certo. =(

Comment: Conseguir algo assim, $resultadoPorc = round(($resulta['total'] * 100) / 354); mas preciso que no lugar no 354 (que foi teste) seja o resultado dinâmico da média de todos atendimentos.

Comment: Faça como nos carrinhos de compra, cria uma variavel $media  = 0 fora do loop e dentro do loop soma ela $media += $soma_total e depois imprima o $media fora do loop novamente.

Comment: Eu até acho que entendi sua ideia, mas não como aplica-la ao meu caso.

Comment: Dá-me uns minutos de momento tou no tel. quando voltar ao PC tenho mostrar-te da forma prática.

Answer (score 3):

Faltou você postar a parte mais importante do seu código que é a estrutura da matriz porém, mesmo sem ela, posso te dar uma orientação matemática de como fazer.

Pelo *table heading* da sua imagem você quer mostrar o percentual de atendimento de cada pessoa (imagino eu). Matematicamente falando, você resolve isso com a velha multiplicação cruzada:

```
A --- B
C --- D
```

Sendo:

```
Total de Atendimentos  --- 100%

Atendimentos da Pessoa --- X
```

Colocando o *sketch* acima numa fórmula matemática, temos:

```
D = BC / A
```

Sendo:

- **A** o Total de Atendimentos
- **B** o percentual total (sempre 100)
- **C** o número de atendimentos da pessoa em questão
- **D** o valor da equação que você precisa descobrir

Aplicando os números na fórmula temos, para a primeira pessoa (322 atendimentos):

```
D = ( 100 * 322 ) / 354
D = 32200 / 354
D = 90,96%
```

Você pode criar uma função que receba três valores e devolva o resultado a ser mostrado onde você precisa, naquela célula da tabela;

```
function getPercentage( $total, $attendances ) {
    return round( ( 100 * $attendances ) / $total );
}
```

E no seu código você invocaria essa função dentro do seu loop o que, a cada iteração produziria um valor diferente. Não posto um exemplo prático de como ficaria pois me faltam informações que provavelmente estão antes do loop postado.

Comment: Bruno, obrigado pelo comentário irei ver aqui o que posso fazer mas acima do que postei de código tenho apenas os selects do banco e algo a mais que (editei) aí.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, não sei se eu interpretei bem a tua dúvida, mas pelo que entendi esse exemplo abaixo talvez de ilumine o caminho.

```
    <?php

    $pessoas = array(
            //id da pessoa => total de atendimentos
            1=>200,
            2=>100,
            3=>400);
    //total da soma de todos os atendimentos que forma a média  = 0;            
    $total = 0;
    //pega-se o valor de cada pessoa
    foreach($pessoas as $id=>$valor){
//atribui-se um loop que faz a soma de todas as médias ao total = soma de todos atendimentos
$total += $valor;
}
    ?>
    <table collspan="5" border="1">
    <tr>
    <th>Atendimentos</th>
    <th>% Media</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    for($i=0;$i<count($pessoas);$i++){
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $pessoas[$i+1]; ?></td>
     //Saída arredondamento (atendimentos da pessoa / média total ) = 0.28... * 100 = 28,... = 29 por excesso/deficiência dependendo.
     //Coloquei $i+1 para que a posição inicial do array não seja 0 e sim 1
    <td><?php echo round($pessoas[$i+1]/$total*100)."%"; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <tr>
    <th>MEDIA GLOBAL</th>
    <th>% GERAL</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $total; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo round(($total/1000)*100)."%"; ?></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

## Espero que isto te ajude, quer com o problema todo, ou apenas com uma parte dele, boa sorte.

Olha, para o caso de banco de dados creio que este outro exemplo pode ajudar-te a chegar a conclusão do primeiro.

## Para o caso de bancos de dados:

```
    <?php
    //No caso de tabelas creio que este exemplo pode ajudar a entender como chegar a conclusão do primeiro
    //Conexão PDO *-* tava com preguiça de escrever o script mysqli
    //Creio que esta parte não te interesse muito também

    try {
$conect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=3;','root','');
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Erro ".$e->getMessage();
    }


   //Aqui o pro é a tabela que eu usei
   //$sql = requisição mysql onde seleciona a id e o preco da tabela e ordena-nos na ordem ascendente       
   $sql = $conect->query("SELECT pro.id,pro.preco FROM pro ORDER BY pro.id,pro.preco ASC");
  //Aqui a nossa variavel id será igual a uma array para poder pegar os campos da tabela em forma de array
  $id = array();
  //O mesmo acontece com a variavel preco
  $preco = array();
  //Aqui enquanto o retorno de busca de objectos na tabela for diferente de falso
  while(false !== ($row= $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))){
//Array id será igual a id
$id[] .= $row->id;
//Array preco será igual a preco
$preco[] .= $row->preco;
}   

   //Aqui pode-se confirmar que na saída os valores são impressos em forma de array     
   print_r($id)."<br/>";
   print_r($preco);
   ?>
```

Isto é a primeira parte, agora, para obter a saída formatada ou configurada, basta adicionar estas linhas de código logo à seguir dos `print_r()`.

## Conclusão:

```
    echo "<hr/>";
    $total = 0;
    foreach($preco as $ids=>$valor){
$total += $valor;
}
    //Aqui podes verificar se o valor de $total bate com os cálculos feitos ou não.
    //echo $total;
    echo "<table border='1' collspan='3'><tr><th>Vendas</th><th>% Media</th></tr>";
    for($i=0;$i<count($id);$i++){
echo "<tr><td>".$id[$i]."</td><td>".round($id[$i]/$total*100)."%"."</td></td></tr>";
}
    echo "<tr><th>Venda Geral</th><th>% Geral</th></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>".$total."</td><td>".(($total/100)*10)."%"."</td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Eu só não entendo como vou fazer esse array para atribuir id => valor no meu caso.

Comment: Digamos que a variavel $pessoas equivale a tua variavel $resulta.

Comment: @phpricardo Olha, adicionei mais uma parte a minha resposta, talvez esta te ajude, no caso a id é uma array e podes pegar cada posição da array seguindo os mesmo passos do primeiro exemplo e depois fazer o mesmo com o valor(no meu caso preço) e fazer a ligação `id=>valor(preco)`