# Percentagens para ficheiros enviados via formulário

Tags: php

Eu tenho um formulário de contacto (PHP) para cada utilizador, e através de cada formulário é possível enviar ficheiros (doc. e pdf) e vai directamente para o utilizador.

Até aqui tudo funciona lindamente, mas preciso de saber a percentagem de ficheiros enviados para cada utilizador, e não sei como lá chegar. Alguém me sabe dar umas luzes?

Comment: Não seria possível salvar os arquivos em uma database e depois puxar o número de linhas que cada usuário (coluna) teria ?

Comment: Mas isso vai sobrecarregar a base de dados, estamos a falar de uma base de dados com mais de mil ficheiros, e eu quero guardar os dados tipo gráfico, para poder aceder sempre que for necessário. Assim posso manter os utilizadores a par de tudo.

Comment: Basicamente você quer um sistema de upload com barra de progresso, certo?

Comment: @BrunoAugusto o meu objectivo é saber a percentagem de ficheiros enviados através de um formulário (que já tenho) para o utilizador X. Para ter noção qual o utilizador que tem maior ficheiros recebidos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com base [nesse comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16507/percentagens-para-ficheiros-enviados-via-formulario?noredirect=1#comment30787_16507) que melhor esclareceu a meta a ser alcançada, deixo como referência [esta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15688/calcular-media-conforme-total-de-uma-celula-em-php/15696#15696), também minha.

---

Seu problema parece ser mais quanto à lógica matemática do que quanto à implementação em si. É simples, basta uma multiplicação cruzada.

Com base na resposta deixada como referência, temos a lógica:

```
A --- B
C --- D
```

Colocando o *sketch* acima numa fórmula matemática, temos:

```
D = BC / A
```

Sendo:

- **A** o total de arquivos enviados
- **B** o percentual total (sempre 100)
- **C** o total de arquivos enviados por usuário
- **D** o valor da equação que você precisa descobrir

Supondo que num mês 500 arquivos tenham sido enviados e o Usuário X enviou 337, temos:

```
D = ( 100 * 337 ) / 500
D = 33700 / 500
D = 67,4%
```

Ou seja, **67,4%** de todos os arquivos enviados para o site.

A segunda parte do seu problema, também coberta no *stack* de referência é executar isso em lote, através de uma função de usuário.

Porém, diferente do cenário citado você talvez não queira exibir esse percentual individualmente, então nesse caso, você cria uma matriz com todos os percentuais e depois a [ordena](http://php.net/sort). Ficaria algo assim:

```
$percentual = array();

while( /** Faz a leitura do recurso vindo do banco */ ) {

    $percentual[ $userID ] = getPercentage( $userUploads, $filesUploaded )
}

sort( $percentuals);

print_r( $percentuals );

function getPercentage( $total, $uploads ) {
    return round( ( 100 * $uploads ) / $total );
}
```

> Foi suprimido a forma como se lê o recurso haja vista variar de acordo com o SGBD e o método de conexão utilziado

No exemplo acima:

- **$userID** é o ID do usuário, mas você pode substituir, talvez, pelo nome de usuário e ter um array associativo pronto para exibição.
- **$userUploads** é o total de arquivos enviados pelo usuário. Pode vir de um COUNT() usado no seu SQL
- **$filesUploaded** é o total de uploads feitos. Pode vir de uma query anteriormente executada ou somando cada COUNT acima. Nesse caso, porém, pode ser preciso quebrar a rotina em dois loops.

A saída poderia ser algo como:

```
Array (

  [X] => 67.4
  [Y] => 16.3
  [Z] => 16.3
)
```

Ou seja, O usuário **X** foi responsável por **67.4%** dos envios enquanto os usuário **Y** e **Z** apenas **16.3%**

Comment: É exactamente isto que procurava. O que me faltava era a lógica, e a parte da implementação. No entanto vou ter de fazer dados individuais para cada utilizador para lhes enviar. De acordo com os X numero de posts teve X numero de ficheiros enviados. Mas com este caminho que me indicou eu consigo lá chegar.